# A longest cycle in a 3-connected graph has a chord

Tags: graph-theory

This is a problem from the Open Problem Garden.
The link is http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/chords_of_longest_cycles.
Several mathematicians have solved the problem for certain families of graphs,
but I believe I found a solution of the general case.

The solution is at http://home.kpn.nl/drooge001/_opg.pdf.
It is less than 2 pages and does not use anything that goes beyond a basic course in graph theory,
also you may need some mathematical maturity to read it.

My question: is this proof OK and, if it is, what should I do next to make it 'official'.

Comment: I rolled this question back to its previous form because, although the proof is incorrect, it is essentially the heart of the question, and is what the answer addresses. The question as you originally posted it is fine for this site, so we might as well keep it around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you contract a mixed edge in $G'$, you will introduce a chord that wasn't originally present in $G$.  To illustrate the idea, consider contracting the orange (mixed) edge below:

[image: a graph with a long chord-free cycle]

If we contract it, we introduce chords that weren't originally present:

[image: a graph with a long chord-free cycle after contracting a "mixed edge"]

(I realize this example is not $3$-connected, but the same idea would apply in the $3$-connected graph, but would be too messy to draw.)

This means that, although the longest cycle in $G / e$ has a chord, the corresponding chord might not be present in $G$.  It is therefore not sufficient to prove the existence of a $3$-contractible mixed edge in the proof of Theorem 0.2.

Comment: Damn, thanks Rebecca.